# Replacing, regex, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Got this string:

```
'test',$, #207
```

I need to remove spaces which have a commma before

So the result will be: `'test',$,#207`

Tried this:

```
  replace(/\/s,]/g, ',')
```

Not working. Any ideas?

Comment: The regex doesn't match your requirement... :) -> https://regex101.com/r/yY1xP3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace **only** spaces and not other `whitespaces` use the following regex.

**Regex**: `/, +/g`

**Explanation**:

`,` will search for comma.

`+` will search for multiple spaces.

And then replace by `,` using `replace(/, +/g, ',')`

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN4rQ9/1)</kbd>**

**<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4zfnv8or/2/)</kbd>**

Comment: @erkino: JSFiddle you added was wrong. I corrected it and added again. Thanx for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since your pattern is simple you can just do this `.split(', ').join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

`replace(new RegExp(find, ', '), ',');`

Comment: Non RE replace() only replaces the first occurence

Comment: Added new RegExp, didn't know that replace only replaced the first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove spaces which have a commma afterwards

No, your example says the opposite. That is, you want to remove spaces that have a comma before them.

In either case, the error in your expression is the "]".

```
replace(/\/s,/g, ',')
```

Does what you say you want to do, and

```
replace(/,\/s/g, ',')
```

Does what the example says.

The other answer is right, though - just use `replace(' ,', '')`; you need no regex here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant comma that have whitespace afterwards:

```
stringVar = "'test',$, #207";
replace('/\,\s/g', stringVar);
```

`\,` means `,` literally and `\s` means whitespace.

You can test javascript regex and know a little more about the modifiers and stuff at [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For all whitespaces which have a "," before

```
var str = "test,$, #207,  th,     rtt878";
console.log(str.replace(/\,\s+/g,","));
var str = "test,$, #207";
console.log(str.replace(/\,\s+/g,","));
```